# Cannot access anonymous function

Tags: javascript, angular, anonymous-function

There are two environments which using the 3rd party library (BrowserPrint.js);

1. [WORKING ENV](https://plnkr.co/edit/Mel98u?p=preview) - JS and jQuery
   where 3party libraries are included simply in the `<head>` part of the document

   and the main function is called in

   ```
   $(document).ready(setup_web_print);
   ```
2. [NOT WORKING ENV](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-browserprint) - Angular, JS and jQuery

   where 3rd party libraries are included in component:

   ```
   import * as $ from 'jquery';
   import * as bp from '../../../content/js/BrowserPrint-1.0.4.js';
   ```

   and triggered in `ngOnInit()` lifecycle hook:

   ```
   ngOnInit() {
      $(document).ready(function () {
       ... 
      })
   ...
   }
   ```

   There is an error in console

   ```
   ReferenceError: finishedFunction is not defined
   at Object.t.getDefaultDevice (BrowserPrint-1.0.4.js:95)
   ```

so it seems it cannot access `finishedFunction`

```
var a = n("GET", e("available"));
        a && (finishedFunction = function(e) {
            response = e, response = JSON.parse(response);
            for (var n in response)
                if (response.hasOwnProperty(n) && response[n].constructor === Array) {
                    arr = response[n];
                    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) arr[i] = new t.Device(arr[i])
                }
            return void 0 == o ? void r(response) : void r(response[o])
        }, i(void 0, a, finishedFunction, s), a.send())
```

Does anybody know how to fix this and why doesn't work with in second env?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't know how JavaScript is handling this comma-written code. But I think this is what you want, isn't it?

```
 if(a) {
    var finishedFunction = function(e) {
      if (response = e, "" == response) return void s(null);
      response = JSON.parse(response);
      var n = new t.Device(response);
      s(n)
    };
    i(void 0, a, finishedFunction, o);
    a.send();
 }
```

Comment: Apparently it'll just evaluate all the arguments then return the last one. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Comment: @GPW thank you for that clarification!  But as far as I can see he is not even reading the return value. So I would say it could be rewritten like I showed.

Comment: Yes, looked reasonable...  And on slightly more careful reading It doesn't look like it'd execute the call to `finishedFunction`if `a` evaluated to false, which is what I thought might be wrong.  Either way, that code is not particularly readable in that form!